# Angular 4 @angular/cli version issues - angular not defined

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have been developing an angular 4 app that works fine when I bundle and compile, but in the console on my web application I get the following:
[image]

I figured it might be an issue because my @angular/cli was on version 1 while all my other @angular's (/common, /compiler, /compiler-cli, /core) were on 4.3.2

So I decided to update all of them and they are now on version 4.3.5 . @angular/cli didn't update though, and it was giving me errors so I manually changed the package.json so it would be updated to 4.3.5 too.

Now my app still works, but when I try to run "npm outdated" I get the following:
[image]

This is what my package.json looks like:

[image]

Can someone please tell me how my package.json should look and what is going on with the "System is not defined" and "angular is not defined"?

## UPDATE

I installed @angular/cli version 1.3.0. I still have the system is not defined and angular is not defined though

Comment: Where do you check the @angular/cli version? Have you checked: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli?

Comment: The Angular CLI version is not on par with the angular framework version. The latest version of  the @angular/cli package is 1.3.0.

Comment: Yup, I reverted back to the correct version, still have angular not defined though

Answer (score 0):

angular/cli is not on version 4.3.5 like angular. It is separate from angular updates.  The most recent version is listed in the npm site https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli

Change the version to the one on the site and then run npm install in your project folder. Hope that helps

Comment: To add to that ... you may want to delete your node_modules folder prior to running `npm install` again.

Comment: I Installed version 1.3.0. Still have the angular is not defined and system is not defined.. any ideas?

Comment: have you changed your angular dependencies in your package version to a version supported by angular cli ? I have a project and the version of angular is 4.2.4 instead of 4.3.5 change this manually and it should fix the problem bro.

Comment: Also I believe "@angular/cli": "1.3.0", should be in the devDependencies object not the dependencies one, in your package.json

Comment: @MauricioDeLaQuintana Can you elaborate please? Do you mean in my package.json? If so that is fixed now.

Comment: @BrianStanley Yes I also changed @angular/cli to dev dependencies, thank you. This hasn't changed my "angular is not defined" unfortunately

Comment: try npm update while in project folder to see if it catches angular/cli now

Answer (score 0):

to answer your comment and to provide you a more elaborate example, this is one example you have to change the version 4.3.5 you currently have

```
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
 "core-js": "^2.4.1",
 "electron": "^1.7.5",
 "ng-cli-electron": "^1.0.3",
 "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
 "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
}
```

after this you can.

```
rm -rf node modules 
npm install
```

hope this works for you bro

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get rid of the 'angular is not defined' and 'system is not defined' doing this.. I'm thinking I need to include something in my index.html